# How to make old JTW token become invalid when user was locked

Tags: identityserver4

I had an identity server 4. When I tried to lock a user, the user still can access APIs, because the JWT token seems still valid.
What should I do?

Comment: You can consider using [reference tokens](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html) instead of plain access tokens

Answer (score 1):

Once a JWT is issued, it stays valid until it naturally expires (`exp` claim in the token).

To invalidate it before that expiration, you would need to **revoke** it. This approach is similar to X.509 certificate revocation. The identity provider would have to track a list of revoked tokens. That revocation list (preferrably secure hashes of revoked tokens) can then be:

- asynchronously distributed over a channel (e.g. Kafka)
- exposed over a service (query list of revoked token hashes, or query if a single JWT is revoked). This poses a significant overhead for JWT verification, as an additional service call is required on each request.

The simpler and recommended solution would be to limit the validity of the JWT (to, let's say, 10 minutes), and use refresh tokens (in a HTTP-only cookie) to refresh the JWT before it expires.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to use short-lived access tokens and use the refresh token to renew the access tokens. Doing a lookup in the API that receives the access token on every request will be pretty expensive performance wise. So

So, its all about what trade-offs that you are willing to make.